# Java: Printing a line once if it contains specific words

Tags: java, string, args

I want to take in a text file (given by args[0]) and line by line, check for words given by all the arguments after args[0] and print each line with an asterisk if it contains said words.

I'm pretty sure the code I have at the moment is good enough to check for one word, but I'm unsure how to check for if a line contains multiple words(given by the args) and only to print the line once if it does.

I supposed that a for loop might work, except it would print a line multiple times if it happened to contain multiple words.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordFinder
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner in = null;
        try
        {
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                if (line.contains(args[1]))
                {
                    System.out.println("* " + line);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("  " + line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot find " + args[0])
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My Programming Teacher mostly gave us this type of assignments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you want to check for all (and)

```
            boolean foundAll = true;
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length && foundAll; ++i) {
                foundAll = foundAll && line.contains(args[i]);
            }
            if (foundAll)
            {
                System.out.println("* " + line);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("  " + line);
            }
```

Or at least one match (or)

```
            boolean foundAny = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
                foundAny = line.contains(args[i]);
                if (foundAny) break;
            }
            if (foundAny)
            {
                System.out.println("* " + line);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("  " + line);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code which works for all words found.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordFinder {
    private static final String DEFAULT_LINE_INDICATOR = "  ";
    private static final String ALL_WORDS_FOUND_INDICATOR = "* ";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                boolean allWordsFound = true;
                String line = in.nextLine();
                for (int index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
                    allWordsFound = line.contains(args[index]);
                    if (!allWordsFound) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                String modifiedLine = allWordsFound ? ALL_WORDS_FOUND_INDICATOR + line : DEFAULT_LINE_INDICATOR + line;
                System.out.println(modifiedLine);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want any word, you can use the following code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordFinder {
    private static final String DEFAULT_LINE_INDICATOR = "  ";
    private static final String WORD_FOUND_INDICATOR = "* ";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                boolean atLeastOneWordFound = false;
                String line = in.nextLine();
                for (int index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
                    atLeastOneWordFound = line.contains(args[index]);
                    if (atLeastOneWordFound) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                String modifiedLine = atLeastOneWordFound ? WORD_FOUND_INDICATOR + line : DEFAULT_LINE_INDICATOR + line;
                System.out.println(modifiedLine);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the args in a set and check  each word of the text until a match is found or eol.